# Persist Component DOM on router change in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am developing a ReactJS app. I have three tabs in my page (view1, view2, view3) for which I am creating three routes using react-router.

I have router code like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ViewBar/>
            </div>
        );
     }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    return (
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Home}>
            <Route path="view1" component={View1} />
            <Route path="view2" component={View2} />
            <Route path="view3" component={View3} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Suppose we open View1, the components of View1 render, then open View2, the components of View2 render then change back to View1. The issue is when I change back to View1, all the components of View1 again render even though the data hasn't changed.
I want the DOM elements of the routes to persist after the first render on changing between different routes.
I read many solutions to the similar problem but those were to persist the UI data and not the DOM elements.

Answer (score 1):

`react-router` rerenders each view based on path changes.

If you want persistent data across views, your best solution is to use a persistent data storage solution such as *redux*, *flux*, *mobx*, etc...

If you just want to handle that manually, you can store data on the parent component and pass setters & getters as props to the child views.

...however, understand that working with react, you are working with a virtual DOM, not the actually on-browser DOM. Expectations of DOM elements to persists is dependent on how you code your app to handle state changes.